# PGBouncer is not reusing connections, but keeps creating new database connections until it runs out

Tags: postgresql, freeradius, pgbouncer

I have several clients (FreeRadius servers) that connect to a single central Pgbouncer.
When I utilise one of these FreeRadius servers I can see that several database connections are created by Pgbouncer.

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'master_db';
```

[image]

When I utilise the same freeradius server again, pgbouncer isn't re-using the existing open connections but keeps creating new ones.  Once I reach over 30 connections the whole database comes to an halt.

**PGbouncer.ini**

```
server_idle_timeout = 10
max_client_conn = 500
default_pool_size = 30
```

**postgresql.conf: (Postgres 13)**

```
max_connections = 150
```

Based on my research Pgbouncer is supposed to allocate a single database connection to a client (from the default_pool_size) and then create as many internal connections the client needs (up to max_client_conn).

But what I observe here is the opposite. What am I missing, please?

**UPDATE:**
The solution Laurenz suggested works but throws this error, when using asyncpg behind the scenes:

`NOTE: pgbouncer with pool_mode set to "transaction" or "statement" does not support prepared statements properly. You have two options: * if you are using pgbouncer for connection pooling to a single server, switch to the connection pool functionality provided by asyncpg, it is a much better option for this purpose; * if you have no option of avoiding the use of pgbouncer, then you can set statement_cache_size to 0 when creating the asyncpg connection object.`

Comment: Looks like you are using session pooling mode and never close sessions.

Comment: Thanks, would you recommend `transaction` or `statement` type of pooling?

Comment: Transaction level is the best, but then you can get problems with temporary tables, prepared statements and other things that live longer than a transaction.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Since I'm using asyncpg, it threw a new error, which I posted in my question. So I ended up using Pgbouncer in transaction mode for freeradius & asyncpg pool for all python connections. This works. Is it a problem of having two pools? Or do you think I should use just Pgbouncer as per error message's alternative solution? Thanks

Comment: @Houman So did you solved this problem?

Comment: @AlexYu Yes. You need to switch to transaction level, so that it closes the connection after it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `session` option for `POOL_MODE` so that it is able to maintain connection sessions opened by asyncpg because of the asynchronous nature

You should the following in your

if using `pgbouncer.ini` file

```
[pgbouncer]
pool_mode = session
...
...
...
```

or if using env variable

```
POOL_MODE=session
```

`extra source:` https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/faq.html#why-am-i-getting-prepared-statement-errors

> If you are getting intermittent prepared statement
> "**asyncpg_stmt_xx**" does not exist or prepared statement
> “**asyncpg_stmt_xx**” already exists errors, you are most likely not
> connecting to the PostgreSQL server directly, but via pgbouncer.
> pgbouncer, when in the "transaction" or "statement" pooling mode, does
> not support prepared statements. You have several options:
>
> if you are using pgbouncer only to reduce the cost of new connections
> (as opposed to using pgbouncer for connection pooling from a large
> number of clients in the interest of better scalability), switch to
> the connection pool functionality provided by asyncpg, it is a much
> better option for this purpose;
>
> disable automatic use of prepared statements by passing
> statement_cache_size=0 to asyncpg.connect() and asyncpg.create_pool()
> (and, obviously, avoid the use of Connection.prepare());
>
> switch pgbouncer’s pool_mode to session.

Comment: This is incorrect. Session is by default and it won't work in this scenario as discussed. The solution is `pool_mode = transaction`

Comment: had similar error and i modified from `transaction` to `session` and it worked for me...using lastest pgbouncer and lastest asyncpg....maybe versions different then

Comment: also read the error message `NOTE: pgbouncer with pool_mode set to "transaction" or "statement" does not support prepared statements properly.` it clearly states that `transaction` does not work...maybe you had a different issue elsewhere then

Comment: The Default value is session. There is no need to set it in that case. Please see the comments of Laurenz Albe under my question. The session mode never closes the connections and this is exactly my problem, because the pool runs out eventually since I have so many FreeRadius servers connecting to the same database.  I want the connections to close after Freeradius is done, hence Transaction is the correct setting. I'm using it on production since July this year without any issues.

Comment: well i had set mine to `transaction` and had to change to `session`...why does it matter that default is session? whether it is default or not...the error message clearly shows what the issue is...if it was left at default then why did the error message happen complaining it should be changed to `session`???

Comment: I don't think you read my comment. pool_mode = session is keeping the connections alive. They accumulate, that's the problem.

Comment: so what was the solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since PgBouncer 1.21.0 it now supports protocol level named prepared statements in transaction pooling mode, which would almost certainly resolve this error. You can turn this support on by setting `max_prepared_statements` to a non-zero value in PgBouncer its config file. For details check the docs: https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#max_prepared_statements